# Add multiple declarations to XDocument

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml, declaration

I'm trying to build an XDocument that requires two declarations. The final document needs to look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><?adf version="1.0"?><adf></adf>
```

It's no problem to add the first declaration but I'm struggling while trying to add the second. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is a declaration, the second a processing instruction. Just call the API to add the processing instruction.

Comment: Here's a link to MSDN page describing it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xprocessinginstruction.aspx